# How to iterate the values of the array in a query?

Tags: php

I want to iterate the values of the array `$code` and `$per_section`from the query below. What looping method should i use? Or is this the right thing to do?

```
   //total students
    $count_query=mysql_query("select total_students from subject where teacherid = '$get_id'");
    while($count_row=mysql_fetch_array($count_query)){ 
    $total += $count_row['total_students'];
    }

    $query = mysql_query( "Select code,total_students from subject where teacherid='$get_id'");
        while($result=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))){
         $section = ($result['total_students']/ $total)*30;
         $per_section[] = round($section, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
         $code[] = $result['code'];
        }

    //perform this statement for a number of times depending on the number of array of $code..
        $user_query=mysql_query("select * from result where subject_id ='$code' and faculty_id = '$get_id'LIMIT $per_section ")or die(mysql_error());                   
        while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($user_query)){
            ...
         }
```

Sample data:
Subject table

```
code    total_students   teacherid

IT230         45         11-0009
IT213         44         11-0009
IT214         40         11-0009
```

result table

```
subject__id    faculty_id

IT230          11-0009
IT213          11-0009
IT214          11-0009
```

Expected Results:
I want to show only 30 records of students that matches the result table.

Since the total students of that teacher are 45, 44, 40 = 129. This is the `$per_section`

IT230 only needed students = (45/129)*30 = 10.46 or i need only 11 of the results.

IT213 only needed students = (44/129)*30 = 10.23 or i need only 10 of the results.

IT214 only needed students = (40/129)*30 = 9.3 or i need only 9 of the results.

I want to search for the records in IT230 and select only 11 of them.
IT213 for only 10 and IT214 for 9. Since i only have 3 records, only these three records will show up.

Comment: mysql_query is deprecated in php5.6 and not supported in php7, use PDO instead http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Also use prepared statements http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php to protect against SQL injection

Comment: don't loop, join the two tables.

Comment: What is `$result['total_students']`? It's not in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: What is $total? Can you explain whole work logic (what you trying to solve/achieve)?

Comment: Updated the $total var, sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: I want to iterate the values of arrays $per_section and $code to the next query.

Answer (score 0):

Use one query that joins the two tables:

```
SELECT s.total_students, s.code, r.*
FROM students AS s
LEFT JOIN result AS r ON r.subject_id = s.code
WHERE s.teacher_id = '$get_id' AND r.faculty_id = '$get_id'
ORDER BY s.code
```

Then you can get all the information in a single loop:

```
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    if (!isset($per_section[$result['code']]) {
        $per_section[$result['code']] = round($result['total_student']/$total*30, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_UP);
        $code[] = $result['code'];
    }
    if ($result['subject_id'] !== null) {
        // do stuff with columns from result table here
    }
}
```

Comment: Sir, i have updated my problem code sir as i forgot to include it. Thank you.

Comment: Your first loop won't work, there's no `$row['total_students']` returned by the query.

Comment: Updated to $result['total_students']. Still no luck sir

Comment: Updated the answer to show how to process the joined query

Comment: It returns only 1 result

Comment: Post sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Updated the question. Thank you for you time sir.

Comment: Can you format it as a table so we can see the relationships? And where is the `id` field in `students`, which gets matched with the variable `$id`? There's nothing in your queries that uses `teacherid` or `faculty_id`, what do they have to do with this? It looks like there's only one row in the `result` table for each `subject_id`, so there will only be one row of results for a specific `$id`.

Comment: What do you mean by "30 records of students"? There are only 3 student records in your sample data.

Comment: Where does the `129` number come from?

Comment: I'm really sorry for the confusion sir. I have updated my problem code. 
How can i format it as a table ?
30 records means, i only need 30 records to be shown out of 129 records.
That 129 is the total of `total_students` in the subject table.

Comment: Paste plain text with the table and then indent it with Ctl-k or the `{}` tool in the SO editor.

Comment: If 129 is the total of `total_students`, what is `$total = 100;` in the code?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments on your question, it is much better practice to use prepared statements via `PDO` and `JOIN` the two tables:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydb', 'username', 'password');

$stmt = $dbh->prepare('
    SELECT result.*
    FROM result
    JOIN student ON result.subject_id = student.code
    WHERE student.id = :id
');

$stmt->execute(['id' => $id]);
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Will practice those things in the near future sir, but before that, i have updated my problem code sir as i forgot to include it.